# Why ‘is there’ omitted in sentences?

Tags: grammar

I’d like to know why ‘is there’ is omitted in the following sentence with grammatical explanation:

> Why the widespread imbalance in their interests and expectations?

Comment: "Why the [noun]?" is an established usage, if slightly informal. "Why the long face?" = "Why are you looking glum?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing has been 'omitted', it is just a different way of saying the same thing.

You expect it should say:

> Why *is there a* widespread imbalance in their interests and expectations?

Notice that I've used the indefinite article, whereas your example uses the definite:

> Why *the* widespread imbalance in their interests and expectations?

I imagine that the wider context of your quotation has already established a few things, such as who "their" refers to; likely it has also hinted towards an 'imbalance'. So, having established which imbalance you're talking about, you can refer to it with the definite article - *the* (aforementioned) imbalance.

There's no need to keep repeating the same things over and over. Consider this exchange:

> -Why are you wearing my coat?
> -I was cold.
> -But why *my* coat?

There's no reason for the person to repeat "*why are you wearing*..." so instead they just ask "why [x]" which is not dissimilar from your example.